# Problem with theorem decimal numbering in LaTeX

Tags: latex, counter, theorem

Below is the beginning of my LaTeX code. When I compile, theorem numbers do not show the decimal point. For example, the output shows Theorem 11 instead of Theorem 1.1. How can I fix this ?

```
\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}    
\smartqed  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,latexsym}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{clm}[thm]{Claim}
\newtheorem{fact}[thm]{Fact}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
```

Answer (score 2):

it looks like this is a setting of the style file you are using (svjour3)

in the version i found [here](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svjour3/global.zip), line 804 contains the line

```
\def\@thmcountersep{}
```

which removes the separator. if you want you can add back the period ( `\def\@thmcountersep{.}` ) but if the style file was provided by a journal their default is probably their default. it may be worth having a look at some example articles from the journal

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick for theorems, but it did not change the references. For example, theorem~\ref{first thm in article} shows as theorem 11 instead of theorem 1.1 in the pdf file. Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: that's odd, works fine for me (i get theorem 1.1 from \ref). have you changed anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a backslash before the period? Perhaps '.' serves some special function when you make theorems.